# umbraco giving 404 on all pages except root. preview works fine

Tags: iis, configuration, umbraco, upgrade

#### BACKGROUND

We are upgrading an umbraco 4.5.2 site running on Win2k8r2 / IIS7.5, SQL2k8r2 to umbraco 4.11.10. Given the number of steps required to perform the upgrade, we chose to do it offline and then replace production with the updated db and file system.
We did an offline upgrade to bring it up to 4.11.10 (4.5.2 -> 4.6.1 -> 4.7.2 -> 4.8.1 -> 4.9.1 -> 4.11.10). These upgrades affected the database and the filesystem.

The old system has 14 domains resolving to the 1 umbraco site. The domains are just aliases and per requirements are not set up with redirects from 13 of the domains to a master - instead, each domain serves the same content - just with a different host.
The 14 host headers are defined in IIS. They are also defined in umbraco under:

```
Content   (folder)
    EN    (language folder)
        Home   (Hostnames are defined here)
        Top Level 1 (also a child of EN)
        Top Level 2 (also a child of EN)
```

#### PROBLEM

When we test under localhost (which is defined in IIS but not as a hostname in umbraco), the site renders content as expected. However, when we test with one of the hosts defined in IIS and in umbraco host names (after setting it up to resolve to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file), we are able to get to the home page but all other pages result in a 404.

The home page and preview pages render fine and the content editor and other backend admin features work fine. However, the "nice url" pages do not render and get 404 errors.

#### WHAT I'VE TRIED

- I have deleted `app_data\umbraco.config` and republished the entire site.
- Create a new website in IIS. Still get the 404 on pages other than site root.
- Looked in umbracoLog table. Didn't see anything about 404s or anything that looked unusual in relation to before/after upgrade but I'm not an umbracoLog expert.

Is it necessary to do a clean install of 4.11.10 to install prerequisites that I may be missing? If so, what are these prerequisites and can they be installed independent of 4.11.10 install?

I'm at a loss as to what might be causing the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any recent changes you are aware of? Recent upgrade, etc?

Comment: @DouglasLudlow, please see question updates above.

Comment: You could possibly be missing some config settings that should have been added during the upgrade process, or there could be some assemblies, in the gac or otherwise, that are available on the offline/staging server that aren't present on the production server. You may want to compare your current config files with ones from a clean 4.11.10 install.

Comment: Can you find any errors in the Event Viewer? 
If the 404 page loads, it might be because there is a default error page displayed. If there is a 500 error, the same default page comes up, looking like a 404 error. 

Otherwise have a look at the notfound handlers config file (config/404handlers.config), and remove one by one to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of items fixed the problem.

1. The main problem was having the hostnames defined in umbraco under the `Home` node. I removed the hostnames defined in umbraco at the `Host` node. Hostnames still exist in IIS.
2. In `config\umbracoSettings.config`

   1. Set `<useDomainPrefixes>` to `false`
   2. Set `<addTrailingSlash>` to `false`
3. In `web.config` set `umbracoUseDirectoryUrls` to `true`
4. Finally, fix a side-effect of removing the umbraco hostnames that causes requests for `/` to resolve to the `EN` node by adding the following to `config\UrlRewriting.config`

---

```
 <add name="SiteRootHack"
      virtualUrl="^~/$"
      rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
      destinationUrl="~/home.aspx"
      ignoreCase="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should check, but if you are getting Umbraco's 404 page and you can access the backoffice then that is a good sign at least!

The first thing to do is check Umbraco's logs at ~/app_data/logs/ to see what Umbraco is logging upon each request, if anything. Then check:

- Have you installed MVC3 and 4 on the server?
- Is the application running in a .Net 4 integrated app pool?
- Have you applied "write" permissions to the correct folders?
- Try removing any domain settings you have in the Umbraco backoffice, these are almost redundant if the site is a basic install.

If possible you should also create an Umbraco project from NuGet, this way everything you need with regards to DLLs dependencies are installed in the project. Also, there shouldn't be any need to upgrade in so many steps. It should be possible to upgrade from 4.5 to 4.7 then to 4.11 directly.

Finally, check the breaking changes in the Umbraco versions. For example, `GetProperty("propertyName").Value` returns a `string` in one version and then was changed to `object` in a latter version possibly 4.11, so this would obviously start causing `NullReference` exceptions which may be inadvertently be causing the 404's. It is unlikely you would be able to upgrade like this without having to make some code changes.

Comment: I did a brand new install of 4.11.10 on the new server with a CE database and was able to create and view a few pages so it looks like the prereqs are all there. But the ported site still gives the 404s.  Yes, the appPool is running in .net4 integrated. Yes, to write permissions. No on mvc3/4.

How do I enable detailed request logging in umbraco?

Comment: You need to have MVC 3 & 4 installed. The simplest way to do this is via Web Platform Installer http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error in my test environment. Installing MVC3 and MVC4 had no effect. The problem still occurred.